# How to render 2 text lines in one?

Tags: pug

How to render in PugJS 2 text lines in one?

For example I except:

```
<p>
  <span class="foo">bar</span> blabla
</p>
```

I try this:

```
p
  span.foo bar
  |  blabla
```

but it renders

```
<p>
  <span class="foo">bar</span>
  " blabla"
</p>
```

Comment: It is rendering properly. The quotes are added if you are inspecting elements in browser console. Otherwise it's same as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`Display: inline-block` is what you're looking for.

e.g

```html
<p>
    <span style="display: inline-block;">Foo</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block">Bar</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
p.
  #[span.foo bar] blabla
```

Check out [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation)